# In JPA, how to get from multiple table in a single entity class

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

```
Entity : Details
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "refId")
private Collection<PersonDetail> PersonDetailCollection;
@Id
@Column(name = "REFERENCE_ID")
private String referenceId;
@Column(name = "PRICE_ID")
private String priceID;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
Getter and Setter of all variable

Entity: PersonDetail 
@JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID", referencedColumnName="REFERENCE_ID")
@ManyToOne
private Details refId;
Getter and Setter of all variable

Entity: PriceDetail
@Id
@Column(name = "PRICE_ID")
private String priceID;
@Column(name = "PRICE")
private String price;
Getter and Setter of all variable
```

Here I have three table from which table Details and PersonDetail have a join. How to get data from these three tables in a single entity without a join on PriceDetail table?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use join in this case? PersonDetail already is in relation with Details, then why not PriceDetail as well?

Comment: The tables are designed in such a way and I don't have the authority to alter it.

Comment: I still don't understand. Details has PRICE_ID and PriceDetails has PRICE_ID, then why cannot you use `... FROM DETAILS D JOIN PRICEDETAIL P ON D.PRICE_ID = P.PRICE_ID` ? Or did you mean that entities cannot be altered?

Comment: Yes, I meant that entities cannot be altered. I want to use the same relation  `DETAILS D JOIN PRICEDETAIL P ON D.PRICE_ID = P.PRICE_ID` but the problem is how to get the data in single entity class Details

Comment: You said entities cannot be altered, are you planning on making a new entity class then?  Or did you mean tables cannot be altered - if so, why not just map the priceId string the same as you have the ref_id field?   If this is a 1:1 type mapping and a Detail cannot exist without a row in the PriceDetail table, look into the SecondaryTable annotations which would allow an entity to span two tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [selecting into new object instance using its  constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

You will have to create a new class, e.g. `DetailsResult` which would have all the properties you need to retrieve. Then you can use the JPQL query to fetch data:

```
"select new your.package.DetailsResult(
<fill here the required constructor arguments, 
that you will get from the query results, like 'd.referenceId' or 'p.priceID'>)
 from Details d, PriceDetail p where d.priceID = p.priceID"
```

I hope this will put you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

try writing NamedNativeQuery in the parent class itself. I think this works.!!